# Error reading assemblies: Error locating assembly descriptor: descriptor.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create a jar file out of a directory
Below is the structure of my files

test-dir -  [Root folder]

src

QE (directory that i want to pack)

descriptor.xml

pom.xml

---

My pom file

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>        
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My descriptor.xml

```
<assembly>
    <id>jar-assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>QE</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

But when i run mvn package , i get the below error

```
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: descriptor.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.753 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-17T18:50:26-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0:single (assemble) on project abc-test: Error reading assemblies: Error locating assembly descriptor: descriptor.xml
[ERROR]
[ERROR] [1] [INFO] Searching for file location: E:\test-dir\descriptor.xml
[ERROR]
[ERROR] [2] [INFO] File: E:\test-dir\descriptor.xml does not exist.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] [3] [INFO] File: E:\test-dir\descriptor.xml does not exist.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: The directory where the `descriptor.xml` is expected does not contain the descriptor....